# Converting BMP image into TAB MapInfo format using MapXtreme?

Tags: gdal, mapinfo, raster-conversion, mapxtreme

I am developing a plugin for MapInfo and I have BMP image with all the prop and I have rectbounds. I have done through GDAL using the below solution. But I am not getting proper output which I am expecting. I am getting some extra white patches in my TAB tab after converstion. I believe this is happening because of GDAL.

This is my code:

```
            Bitmap bmp = CreateChartTIF(path);

            GdalConfiguration.TryConfiguration();

            String wktProj = null;
            String tmpPath = @"E:\@@MapInfo_1\tmp.bmp";
            int a = Convert.ToInt16(rectBounds.Left);
            int b = Convert.ToInt16(rectBounds.Top);

            bmp.Save(tmpPath, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            System.IO.MemoryStream mem = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            mem.Flush();

            String[] options = null;
            Gdal.AllRegister();
            OSGeo.GDAL.Driver srcDrv = Gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff");
            Dataset srcDs = Gdal.Open(tmpPath, Access.GA_ReadOnly);
            Dataset dstDs = srcDrv.CreateCopy(@"E:\@@MapInfo_1\Output\2-0.tif", srcDs, 0, options, null, null);

            Osr.GetWellKnownGeogCSAsWKT("WGS84", out wktProj);
            dstDs.SetProjection(wktProj);

            double minx = rectBounds.Left;
            double miny = rectBounds.Bottom;


            double maxx = rectBounds.Right;
            double maxy = rectBounds.Top;


            double mapWidth = Math.Abs(minx - maxx);
            double mapHeight = Math.Abs(maxy - miny);

            double pixel1 = mapWidth / bmp.Width;
            double pixel2 = mapHeight / bmp.Height;



            //Top Left x, w-r pixel resln, 0, Top Letf y, 0, n-s pixel resln
            double[] geoTransfo = new double[] { minx, pixel1, 0, maxy, 0, pixel2 * (-1) }

            dstDs.SetGeoTransform(geoTransfo);

            dstDs.FlushCache();
            dstDs.Dispose();
            srcDs.Dispose();
            srcDrv.Dispose();
            bmp.Dispose();


            RasterProcessing.Convert(@"E:\@@MapInfo_1\Output\2-0.tif", "E:\\@@MapInfo_1\\Jonathan_Test.mrr", "MI_MRR");
```

Please find the screenshot below :

[image: Screenshot of MapInfo]

Any idea or any sample code? Is there any way to remove GDAL dependency and do this conversion using MapXtreme?

Comment: How do you know the rectBounds?

Comment: @user30184 my client has provided me the rectbonds of all the charts. Which are correct as this is working in ArcsGIS , Mechai and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by changing the driver string which is :

`RasterProcessing.Convert(@"E:\@@MapInfo_1\Output\2-0.tif", "E:\\@@MapInfo_1\\Jonathan_Test.tif", "MI_GeoTiff_IMG");`

Answer (score 0):

MapInfo .tab files are just text files; it is quite easy to create them yourself.

A .tab file for a registered image looks like this:

```
!table
!version 300
!charset WindowsLatin1

Definition Table
  File "test.png"
  Type "RASTER"
  (10000,7500) (0,0) Label "top left",
  (20000,7500) (256,0) Label "top right",
  (10000,0) (0,192) Label "bottom left"
  CoordSys Earth Projection 8, 104, "m", -123, 0, 0.9996, 500000, 0
  Units "m"
```

- `CoordSys` is the projection (here: WGS84 / UTM zone 10 north); look the numbers up in the `mapinfow.prj` file, or create a test .tab file with the correct projection.
  (With a lat/lon projection, you have `Units "degree"`.)
- The six pairs of numbers specify how to map image pixel coordinates to map coordinates. The first pair in each line are the X/Y map coordinates (usually, Y is bottom-to-top), the second pair are the pixel coordinates (Y top-to-bottom). Here, I have put the registration points at three image corners; the image size is 256×192 pixels, and the map coordinates are left:10000, right:20000, bottom:0, top:7500.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have changed driver ID from MI_MRR  to MI_GeoTiff_IMG and my problem solved. Now there is no white patches.

Comment: I have one more question why my map is changing when I am loading the charts. sometimes its height is getting big and sometime width. Have any idea ? How to control this

Comment: That would be a different question.

Comment: I know that. But if you can help in this here itself

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a forum; questions and answers are more useful for other people if they are actually entered as questions and answers. Please add `MI_GeoTiff_IMG` as an actual answer. Please read the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour), and any appropriate [help pages](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help).